# How to compile and run HelloWorld.java example from Sphinx4 without and IDE in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jar, sphinx4

I have been testing the examples (HelloWorld.java) from Sphinx4 with Eclipse, but I would like to compile and run them from the command line.
The application needs 5 .jars to be able to run, I have read that in order to compile a java class with multiple .jars I need to execute the following command (as an example I will show short names):

```
javac -cp one.jar:two.jar:three.jar:four.jar:five.jar HelloWorld.java
```

The console does not throw any error messages:

```
parias001@parias001-pc:~/Projects/citadel_voices/sphinx_test > javac -cp jsapi.jar:sphinx4.jar:TIDIGITS_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar:WSJ_8gau_13dCep_8kHz_31mel_200Hz_3500Hz.jar:WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar HelloWorld.java
parias001@parias001-pc:~/Projects/citadel_voices/sphinx_test >
```

I think that the compilation succeeded. Now I would like to run the application, I read that in order to do this, I have to execute the command as follows (Using short name example as before):

```
java -cp one.jar:two.jar:three.jar:four.jar:five.jar HelloWorld
```

This is the message that the console throws:

```
parias001@parias001-pc:~/Projects/citadel_voices/sphinx_test > java -cp jsapi.jar:sphinx4.jar:TIDIGITS_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar:WSJ_8gau_13dCep_8kHz_31mel_200Hz_3500Hz.jar:WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

I don't know what is going on here, I should also say that I do not have a lot of experience using external .jars.

The names of the .jars are:

1. jsapi.jar
2. sphinx4.jar
3. TIDIGITS_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar
4. WSJ_8gau_13dCep_8kHz_31mel_200Hz_3500Hz.jar
5. WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.jar

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Are you sure your `HelloWorld.java` file includes a proper `main` method?

Comment: Where is HelloWorld.class?

Comment: I am 100% sure that HelloWorld.java contains a valid main method.

Comment: All the files are contained in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include current directory in classpath:

```
java -cp .:one.jar:two.jar:three.jar:four.jar:five.jar HelloWorld
```

Note the leading `.:`

---

From this [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I included the "." but now it shows another error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/helloworld/HelloWorld)`

I guess I know what the problem is, in the HelloWorld.java code, there is included a package as well:
"package edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.helloworld;"

If I need to compile with a package, should I follow the same instructions as before?

Thank you.

Comment: I just commented the line with the package, now everything is working as it should! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't want to comment the package you have to put classes in a hierarchy of folder corresponding to the path (ie. package a.b.c => path a/b/c)